# How to print EPL barcode vertically in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, zebra-printers, barcode-printing, neodynamic

How to print bar-code in vertically direction through PRN File?

**Printer  : Zebra GC420t** **EPL**

[image]

I had designed the Barcode using Zebra Designer code and generate the prn file.
But when I Print barcode, print comes in Horizontally format,I had made changes printer property still not coming vertically, My Barcode Sticker is 
**5 cm (Width) X  27 cm (Height)**

Below is my prn file code

```
I8,A,001


Q0001,0
q831
rN
S2
D15
ZT
JF
O
R0,0
f100
N
A495,174,2,1,1,1,N,"1"
A494,107,2,1,1,3,N,"1"
A764,103,2,4,1,1,N,"Vehicle No : "
A766,176,2,4,1,1,N,"Container No : "
B780,379,2,1,7,21,160,N,"$Zendor"
X0,399,1,0,400
P1
```

How to do? kindly help. I had to make any changes in PRN File? Kindly Suggest.